# Mat-form-field does not work

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I make a table using Material Angular. Added sorting and pagination. But when I want to add a form for filtering everything gets off and in the end nothing works. What could I have done wrong? The component has been added to the project module.

[Before](http://mepic.ru/view/?id=583ece377fdc445b2aeb5c85c34b7d5b) using the component **Mat-form-field** and after [use](http://mepic.ru/view/?id=64ed99751a808598be8eb69884eebf49).

Here is an example of html and ts files:

HTML:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <div class="example-header">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
                [pageSize]="20"
                [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
  </mat-paginator>

</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort, MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  constructor()  { }


  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

  export interface Element {
    name: string;
    position: number;
    weight: number;
    symbol: string;
  }

  const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
    {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
    {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
    {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
    {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
    {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
    {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
    {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
    {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
    {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
    {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
    {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
    {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
    {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
    {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
    {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
    {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
    {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
    {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
    {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
    {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},
  ];
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For me it's working fine. Did you import the following dependencies?

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
npm install --save @angular/animations
```

In your app.module.ts

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from 
    '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule, MatTableModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatSortModule } 
from '@angular/material';
```

And remember to add a theme in your styles.css:

```
 @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

**For Official Reference:**
https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: Have issue here with CSS not applying there is no mention in the doc for `@import ~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css`; or any themes if you choose a built in I thought it would modify and add the import but doesn't look like this is the case.

Comment: It seems like the way to apply pre-built css has changed in the newer versions. Check this link in the documentation for Angular Material version 13.2.1

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme

Specifically:

"You can find the pre-built theme files in the "prebuilt-themes" directory of Angular Material's npm package (@angular/material/prebuilt-themes). To include the pre-built theme in your application, add your chosen CSS file to the styles array of your project's angular.json file"

Comment: In my case, it was just the css import. I never had to do it, not sure why now. Do remember needing to manually add the import of css. Thanks 

Comment: I'm just having this very beginner question. How to add  @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; to may styles.sass? it already has import for bootstrap and when I add another line for import it complains. What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: @William would need more information about your issue. I recommend you to ask a new question and share your project's code.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. I was missing the `MatInputModule`. The `FormsModule` was unnecessary.

Strangely though, when I commented out the `<mat-form-field>` it would work but w/o the expected format which is expected.

Answer (score 0):

- I also had got the same error, when using with angular 17 I followed chat GPT this is what it gave and also worked for me.
- The error message you're encountering ('mat-form-field' is not a known element) suggests that Angular cannot recognize the  element, which is a part of Angular Material.
- To resolve this issue, ensure that you have imported MatFormFieldModule into your module file (app.module.ts or the relevant module where you're using mat-form-field).
- Here's an example of how you should import and include MatFormFieldModule in your module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ... your components
  ],
  imports: [
    // ... other modules
    MatFormFieldModule, // Ensure MatFormFieldModule is imported here
  ],
  // ... other configurations
})
export class YourModule { }
```

Ensure that:

1. The import statement (MatFormFieldModule) is present in the file.
2. The module where you're using  includes MatFormFieldModule in the imports array of the @NgModule.
   After making this change, if you're still facing the issue, try stopping and restarting the Angular development server (ng serve) to ensure that the changes take effect.